# build libvpx for visual studio 2012 with Cygwin

Tags: visual-studio-2012, makefile, cygwin, libvpx

I have some problem. I want to use `libvpx` for encoding frame on VS 2012 Express.

First step, I installs Cygwin and gcc, make, and yasm packages.

Second, I downloads `libvpx` and creates "build" folder for building `libvpx`.

Third, I run this command in "build" folder.

`../libvpx/configure --target=x86-win32-vs11 --enable-static-msvcrt`

Finally, I run `make` command. However, it return the message:

`"msbuild.exe not found in path"`

My OS is windows 7 64 bit.
How do I fix it? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Well, have you checked that (1) you have "msbuild.exe" on your machine; (2) folder added to path?

Comment: I have "msbuild.exe" at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319. But I don't know that where is "path" in "msbuild.exe not found in path".

Answer (score 0):

Running make from the mingw shell will have created a solution file which you can open with visual studio and then build the project.